# Condition to conclude that $g$ be an open map

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a local homeomorphism and let $g:Y\to X$ be a continous function such that $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_Y$. Is it true that $g$ is an open map? If yes, why? Do even weaker conditions suffice, e.g. $f$ being continous and open?

Comment: The mere existence of a global section seems like a strong enough requirement. For instance, if $f$ is a covering then the existence of $g$ implies that $f$ is in fact a homeomorphism, and the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma. The map $g$ is a local homeomorphism, in particular, it is open.

Proof. Consider a point $q\in Y$ and its image $p=g(y)$. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $p$ in $X$ such that $f|U: U\to V=f(U)$ is a homeomorphism. Since $f\circ g|V =id_V$, it follows that $g|V: V\to U$ is the inverse of $f|U$. Thus, $g|V: V\to U$ is a homeomorphism (since $f|U: U\to V=f(U)$ is a homeomorphism). qed